# Expand full virtual debian disk to use empty space

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, disk-space-utilization

I have a virtual server running Debian 8 with a completely full primary disk. I have expanded the "physical" hard drive through my hypervisor, but I can't figure out how to expand the primary partition to use the newly created unallocated space on the virtual disk.

I've expanded the virtual disk from 4GB to 10GB.

`fidks -l` output:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (8388607 != 20971519) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 58BB252B-F2A7-48A3-9270-BB80B698AC35

Device       Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048 1050623 1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 6293503 5242880  2.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  6293504 8386559 2093056 1022M Linux swap
```

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            438M     0  438M   0% /dev
tmpfs            90M   11M   80M  12% /run
/dev/sda2       2.4G  2.4G     0 100% /
tmpfs           449M     0  449M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           449M     0  449M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  132K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            90M     0   90M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Important note:** this is an incredibly bare-bones system with very few utilities on it, and due to the nonexistant disk space I cannot install anything.

I'm looking for a way to expand the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prerequisites

   - Everything is doable one-shot within the VM, without reboot, *if* `/` (`/dev/sda2`) is an online resizable filesystem. You never told what filesystem is `/` . I'll assume it's `ext4` (`xfs` works too, some others might too).
   - It' a VM, do a backup before continuing.
   - Install gdisk. Don't use `fdisk` but `gdisk`: `fdisk` doesn't always handle well the GPT PMBR issue I describe below, `gdisk` has no trouble with it. Installation size is less than 1M.
2. Actions to do on partitions

   - `swapoff /dev/sda3` to prepare its removal: it's in the way and not vital.
   - run `gdisk /dev/sda` . Take notice of the warning about GPT PMBR: that's because EFI writes its label informations both at start and end of disk. So when you enlarged the disk, the new end has not anymore the GPT signature and data. `gdisk` corrects these informations and asks to confirm: just accept. `fdisk` can fail at this step (done at the final w for fdisk).
   - (optional) note the to-be-altered partitions' unique GUID (`i` `2` and `i` `3`) for reuse after next steps.
   - delete partition 3 (the swap) with `d` and `3`, else you can't enlarge partition 2.
   - the tricky part: delete partition 2 (`d` `2`). (Re)Create partition 2 (`n` `2`) *on the same spot*: choose the same start (`1050624`) and a bigger size or bigger end, so you'll have more space available, eg `+7G`. Partition type `8300`. If you're told that a signature of an old filesystem was detected, don't erase it, that's your running system there.
   - Recreate a new partition 3 for swap (`n` `3`),proposed default start, and probably same size as before, type `8200`.
   - (optional) restore the previous noted partitions' unique GUID, needed if some configured disk settings depend on it (`PARTUUID=...`), using expert options (`x` then resp. for partitions 2 and 3 `c` `2` and `c` `3`).
   - Write changes (`w` confirm...). You'll get an error about kernel not using the new partition table. That's expected. Quit (`q`).
3. Fix the kernel's view problem with the `partx` command

   - "moved" swap's partition

     ```
     # cat /sys/class/block/sda3/start #kernel's view of the old sda3 partion's position
     6293504
     # partx -u /dev/sda3
     # cat /sys/class/block/sda3/start
     (some higher value)              #kernel's view of sda3 is fixed
     ```
   - **!!** If you don't get an higher value at this step, abort and reboot: the kernel will get the new geometry after the reboot (but it will complain about the swap not available) and skip to step 4.
   - enlarged root fs' partition

     ```
     # cat /sys/class/block/sda2/size #kernel's view of the old partition's size
     5242880
     # partx -u /dev/sda2
     # cat /sys/class/block/sda2/size
     (some bigger value)              #kernel's view of sda2 is fixed
     ```
4. filesystem

   - Reuse a swap, and enlarge the filesystem: now there's room in the partition, the filesystem inside can use that room.

     ```
     # mkswap /dev/sda3
     # swapon /dev/sda3
     # resize2fs /dev/sda2 # ext4 can be resized "online" ie while mounted.
     ```
   - or for xfs:

     ```
     # xfs_growfs /
     ```

You're set. Verify that it's still ok after a reboot. Else, well there's the backup.